# Why is DataGridView not working with "WHERE LIKE" query?

Tags: sql-server, database, vb.net, visual-studio

Visual Basic, Visual Studio 2022. Local mdf Database, the Service-based Database that comes with Visual Studio.

I have a DataGridView showing a table and a TextBox to search values.
The DataSet has this query "SearchInventory"(created with the [Query Configuration Wizard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJhjL.png)):

```
SELECT        id, name, [desc], price
FROM            tableInventory
WHERE        (name LIKE '%' + @Param1 + '%')
```

Using the Query Configuration Wizard to test it works perfectly.

But, when I use the TextBox to search

```
InventoryTableAdapter.SearchInventory(InventoryDataSet.inventoryTable, txtSearch.text)
```

It only shows the values when the match is exactly, bassically ignoring the "LIKE" instruction. Using the Preview Data to test doesn't work either.

Replacing the parameter with a fixed value "shovel" the Preview Data and the DataGridView show the values as intended

```
SELECT        id, name, [desc], price
FROM            tableInventory
WHERE        (name LIKE '%shovel%')
```

Comment: It wouldn't make a difference when it comes from a TextBox. Maybe you need to trim() the value you get from TextBox.

Comment: Can you show us the code that runs the query?

Comment: This is the line:
InventoryTableAdapter.SearchInventory(InventoryDataSet.inventoryTable, txtSearch.text)
Using "shovel" instead of txtSearch doesn't work either.
Using "iron shovel" (the full value) works

Comment: Can you show me the code of SearchInventory?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean or where to find it, I created the query using the Query Configuration Wizard and the "InventoryTableAdapter..."  line is how I call the querys to display them on the DataGridView

Comment: @NessunRdz edit your question to include code. No one should have to read through the comments to understand the context of your question.

Comment: Be careful of SQL Injection unless you sanitize the parameter value before you use it against the database or someone WILL take advantage or worse.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: The code you posted shows one parameter but the linked image shows two. Did you actually test it with one?

Comment: @jmcilhinney yes, the linked image is the project I am working on and where I found the problem, for the Post I translated and simplified, but it's essentially the same

Comment: I asked two questions and you didn't actually answer either of them. Did you actually test with one parameter? It might not matter but you don't know that for sure. The potential issue is also linked to my first question: what database are you using?

Comment: @jmcilhinney Does this answer your question?
"Local mdf Database, the Service-based Database that comes with Visual Studio."

Comment: So the answer is SQL Server then. An MDF file is a SQL Server data file. In that case, what I had in mind as a potential cause does not apply.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The Query is not wrong.
The code to call the Query is not wrong.

Or they are(?), I mean the *WHERE LIKE query* isn't the right method.

You need to use the **Filter** Property on the Binding Source.
**NOTE:** This property *filters* the values **already displayed** on the DataGrid so you need to **fill it first**.

This is the Procedure to solve the Post Question:

```
Private Sub SearchFilter(valueSearch As String)
    Dim bSource As New BindingSource
    bSource.DataSource = dataGridInventory.DataSource
    bSource.Filter = "(name LIKE '%" & valueSearch & "%')"
    dataGridInventory.DataSource = bSource.DataSource
End Sub
```

And obviusly you won't need the Query *SearchInventory* made with the QueryWizard.

In case you need to search on two columns, just change the Filter

```
    bSource.Filter = "(name LIKE '%" & valueSearch & "%')
                      OR ([desc] LIKE '%" & valueSearch & "%')"
```

Microsoft Documentation:
[BindingSource.Filter Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.filter)